# Angularjs Custom Directive for table creation

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create a angularjs directive which can be used in many pages, The directive should handle the html table creation, It can have different columns depending upon the requirement of the page. What should be the starting point to write this directive where user we can have different columns in different pages but having one directive only.

Example can be for home page

```
 <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th> 
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

for about page

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Address</th> 
    <th>City</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please follow this link hope it helps you http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2016/04/08/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-for-beginners/

Answer (score 2):

```
var tableDirective = function(){
    return {
       restrict: 'EA', //E = element, A = attribute, C = class, M = comment         
        scope: {
            data: '='         
            },
            templateUrl: 'table-directive.html',
        }
};

angular.module('myModule').directive('tableDirective', tableDirective);
```

table-directive.html:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="item in data.headList">{{ item.name }}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in data.rowList">
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.surname }}</td> 
    <td>{{ item.propertyName }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then, you can use directive and pass data :

```
<table-directive data="data"></table-directive>
```

Here `data` come from controller:

```
...
$scope.data = {
   headList: [{ name: 'Company' }, { name: 'Address' }, { name: 'City' }],
   rowList: // here will be your data
}
...
```

Comment: There are multiple tables in different pages and couple of  pages will have text and text box in the same cell of the table but other tables wont have, one table will have text and icon in the same cell of the row so the behavior of table  cells  change with respect to page plus headers of tables are different from what we get in $scope.data, so i'm wondering if we can achieved this kind of customization using one angular js custom directive.

Comment: @zumuhu, I understood

Comment: Would you suggest/advise me for the last question:
"There are multiple tables in different pages and couple of pages will have text and text box in the same cell of the table but other tables wont have, one table will have text and icon in the same cell of the row so the behavior of table cells change with respect to page plus headers of tables are different from what we get in $scope.data, so i'm wondering if we can achieved this kind of customization using one angular js custom directive. "